# InAppBilling is not reliable

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-checkout

I do have an App at the PlayStore and a major problem with the current version. Everyday I get a lot of mails from customers saying that they paid for the InAppItem, but didn't get it.

There are two manifestations:

1. The customer receives a confirmation mail from google including the order number. But the order number is NOT in my Google checkout account. So Google is billing the customer, but I do not receive the money and my customer is not receiving the item. Even so it has been paid! If he tries to buy the item again an error message occurs, stating: 'failed: you already own this item"
2. The customer receives the item two days after purchasing it. But much earlier than that I can see the successful withdrawal on my checkout account.

Case 1 is very irritating and troublesome, as the customer wants money back, which I never received! In my opinion it's obvious, that this error is caused by Google, since in general this is not a problem and Google is sending these confirmation mails.

Is there someone, who had or have similar problems?
How can I contact Google regarding this matter? I did receive an answer asking me for details, but after describing it, I didn't get any response. Now I feel like they left me alone with my problem.

Comment: This sounds more like a support matter [than a SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to upgrade your app to the [In App billing v3 api](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html). It is way more reliable that the version 2.